# Break between words when line becomes too full

Tags: line-breaking, plain-tex

This example:

```
\font\standard="Arial Unicode MS" at 10pt
\standard

\newlanguage\nohyphens
\language=\nohyphens

\hsize = 150mm
\parindent = 0pt

\vbox{
  \setbox2=\hbox{\hskip12pt‣\hskip3dd}
  \hangindent=\wd2\leavevmode\box2 kopf- und fußgesteuerte Schleife, boolesche Ausdrücke, boolesche Operatoren, Struktogramme, Struktogramme, Struktogramme, Struktogramme
}

\bye
```

gives this overfull hbox:

[image: without tolerance]

How can I tell TeX to put the first "Struktogramme" in a new line, so the box isn't overfull anymore?

I tried setting `\tolerance=10000` but that gives this strange breaking point:

[image: with tolerance]

Comment: Without hyphenation there are too few breakpoints for acceptable line breaks. Therefore I would switch to `\raggedright`.

Comment: Good point and I will do that. And your comment made me thinking about what an "acceptable" line break is and it came to my mind that I have to set a high \emergencystretch to make the point before "Struktogramme" acceptable. You should make an answer from that.

Comment: A high `\emergencystretch` indeed looks unacceptable to my eyes. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the language setting `\language=\nohyphens` hyphenation is disabled. Then there are too few breakpoints for acceptable line breaks (and especially with a language that has long words).

As you have found `\emergencystretch` would help, but the costs are unacceptable large gaps between words.

Therefore it makes sense to switch from full justification to flush left
by using `\raggedright`.